# Pairs and projections in Coq

Tags: coq

I took the following code from https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html:

```
Inductive prod (A B:Type) : Type :=
  pair : A -> B -> A * B

where "x * y" := (prod x y) : type_scope.

Add Printing Let prod.

Notation "( x , y , .. , z )" := (pair .. (pair x y) .. z) : core_scope.



Section projections.
  Context {A : Type} {B : Type}.

  Definition fst (p:A * B) := match p with (x, y) => x end.
  Definition snd (p:A * B) := match p with (x, y) => y end.


End projections.
```

When I load it into CoqIDE, at `Definition fst...` it comes up with the message `The constructor pair (in type prod) expects 4 arguments.`. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Set Implicit Arguments.
```

to the top of the file.